# How to get number of gmail messages by contact (email id) in Android with minimum number of API calls?

Tags: android, gmail-api

What is the best way to get messages by contact/emailId with timestamp in android with minimum number of API calls?

Comment: Do you mean messages sent by a certain email address?

Comment: @Tholle   Yes. Messages sent to me by certain email address, or messages sent by me to that email address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [list messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) that are sent to/from a certain email address:

**Request**

```
q = to:example@gmail.com OR from:example@gmail.com

GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=To%3Aexample%40gmail.com+OR+from%3Aexample%40gmail.com&access_token={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

**Response**

```
{
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": "1516c4a48a1d6ec9",
   "threadId": "1516c3bc5769405d"
  },
  {
   "id": "1516c46d828b2470",
   "threadId": "1516c3bc5769405d"
  }, ...
 ],
 "resultSizeEstimate": 6
}
```

Then you would have to [get these messages individually](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get), just asking for the timestamp if that is all you need (this can be done as a single http-request with a [batch](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch)-request, but will still draw just as many points from your API quota)

**Request**

```
fields = internalDate

GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/1516c4a48a1d6ec9?fields=internalDate&access_token={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

**Response**

```
{
 "internalDate": "1449220786000"
}
```

The `internalDate` represents when the message was stored at Google, in ms since the epoch.